# Selecting a car listing with its images in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this query that selects a `CAR` together with it `IMAGES` from a `MySQL` database.

```
SELECT car.*, comments.*, person.*, body_type.* FROM car
INNER JOIN person
ON person.car_id = car.car_id 
INNER JOIN comments
ON comments.car_id = car.car_id 
INNER JOIN body_type
ON body_type.bodytype_id = car.bodytype_id
INNER JOIN images
ON images.car_id = car.car_id
ORDER BY added_on DESC
```

However, this actually counts the images from the `IMAGES` and returns one listing as many times as there are images from the table. For instance, if there are five images from the `IMAGES` table, it will return one `CAR` Listing Five times, when I actually want display the five images and associate them with one ***CAR*** using the `CAR ID`. I noticed that the problem was in the query because when I removed `INNER JOIN images ON images.car_id = car.car_id`, the Cars are displayed just the right way except, without the images.

Comment: "this actually counts the images"  No, it does not. When you add a field (i.e. `name`) from the table `images` it also shows the name of the image (if that is present in the table images)

Comment: That is true, but everything I said in the initial question is also true

Comment: No, your query results in duplicate lines. The counting is not done by MySQL, but YOU are counting....

Comment: @Luuk thanks for the insight. Which part of the query do you think I should alter to make it doesn't count?

Comment: You already answered that in your question.  To get a list of the images, you need to do an extra query like   `SELECT * FROM images ON images.car_id = car.car_id`

Comment: @Luuk you're being mean for absolutely no reason, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you wand to get the number of images for each car? Maybe this will help you (untested):

```
SELECT car.*, comments.*, person.*, body_type.*, count(*) as countImages
FROM car
INNER JOIN person
ON person.car_id = car.car_id 
INNER JOIN comments
ON comments.car_id = car.car_id 
INNER JOIN body_type
ON body_type.bodytype_id = car.bodytype_id
INNER JOIN images
ON images.car_id = car.car_id
GROUP BY car.car_id
ORDER BY added_on DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, GROUP BY actually solves the problem, although COUNT was causing problems